# "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'" thrown in pct_change

Tags: python, pandas

I have some code that reads stock data with the pandas DataReader.  That works perfectly.  But I also need to read from CSV files.  When I attempt to process it (with the same code I used on the DataReader data), I get "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'" in `pct_change`.  I thought maybe the CSV had some corrupt numbers in it, but it happens even on a small file like this:

```
1979-01-01  226.0
1979-01-02  226.8
1979-01-03  218.6
1979-01-04  223.2
1979-01-05  225.5
1979-01-08  223.1
1979-01-09  224.0
```

Here's the code that throws the error:

```
def sim_leverage(proxy, leverage=1, expense_ratio = 0.0, initial_value=1.0):
    pct_chg = proxy.pct_change(1)
    pct_chg = (pct_chg - expense_ratio / 252) * leverage
    sim = (1 + pct_chg).cumprod() * initial_value
    sim[0] = initial_value
    return sim
```

The `proxy` argument is a DataFrame returned from `DataReader` (works) or `read_csv()` (doesn't work).  I have no clue where / why `pct_change` is accessing strings...!?

Here's the code that reads the data:

```
    if base_sym is None:    # Read base symbol data from file?  Filename in base_start
        base = pd.read_csv(base_start)
    else:
        base = web.DataReader(base_sym, "yahoo", base_start, end_date)["Adj Close"].rename(base_sym)
```

Python 3.8.13, pandas 1.3.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a test of `read_csv()` using your file contents (columns are separated by two spaces, as in the question text):

```py
import pandas as pd
base = pd.read_csv('base_start.txt')
print(f"columns\n{base.columns}")
print(base)
```

Results:

```
columns
Index(['1979-01-01  226.0'], dtype='object')
   1979-01-01  226.0
0  1979-01-02  226.8
1  1979-01-03  218.6
2  1979-01-04  223.2
3  1979-01-05  225.5
4  1979-01-08  223.1
5  1979-01-09  224.0
```

It looks like it isn't detecting any separators but rather reading strings like `'1979-01-09  224.0'` as values in a single column, and it's also inferring that the first row is a column heading `'1979-01-01  226.0'`. So the error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'" raised by `pct_change()` is apparently referring to successive string values in this lone column.

You can try calling `read_csv()` and `sim_leverage()` like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
def sim_leverage(proxy, leverage=1, expense_ratio = 0.0, initial_value=1.0):
    pct_chg = proxy.pct_change(1)
    pct_chg = (pct_chg - expense_ratio / 252) * leverage
    sim = (1 + pct_chg).cumprod() * initial_value
    sim[0] = initial_value
    return sim

base = pd.read_csv('base_start.txt', sep='  ', header=None, engine='python')
print(f"base:\n{base}")
sim = sim_leverage(base[1])
print(f"sim:\n{sim}")
```

Results:

```
base:
            0      1
0  1979-01-01  226.0
1  1979-01-02  226.8
2  1979-01-03  218.6
3  1979-01-04  223.2
4  1979-01-05  225.5
5  1979-01-08  223.1
6  1979-01-09  224.0
sim:
0    1.000000
1    1.003540
2    0.967257
3    0.987611
4    0.997788
5    0.987168
6    0.991150
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

Note that if we don't use the `engine-'python'` argument, this code raises the following warning:

```
 ParserWarning: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support regex separators (separators > 1 char and different from '\s+' are interpreted as regex); you can avoid this warning by specifying engine='python'.
  base = pd.read_csv('base_start.txt', sep='  ', header=None)
```

**UPDATED:**

Based on OP comments, here's an update to what I am seeing.

Contents of .csv input file:

```
Date,Close
1979-01-01,226.0
1979-01-02,226.8
1979-01-03,218.6
1979-01-04,223.2
1979-01-05,225.5
1979-01-08,223.1
1979-01-09,224.0
```

Python code:

```
import pandas as pd
def sim_leverage(proxy, leverage=1, expense_ratio = 0.0, initial_value=1.0):
    pct_chg = proxy.pct_change(1)
    pct_chg = (pct_chg - expense_ratio / 252) * leverage
    sim = (1 + pct_chg).cumprod() * initial_value
    sim[0] = initial_value
    return sim

base = pd.read_csv('base_start.txt')
print(f"base:\n{base}")
sim = sim_leverage(base['Close'])
print(f"sim:\n{sim}")
```

Alternative code for calling `sim_leverage()` (gives the same output):

```py
sim = sim_leverage(base.iloc[:,1])
```

Output:

```
base:
         Date  Close
0  1979-01-01  226.0
1  1979-01-02  226.8
2  1979-01-03  218.6
3  1979-01-04  223.2
4  1979-01-05  225.5
5  1979-01-08  223.1
6  1979-01-09  224.0
sim:
0    1.000000
1    1.003540
2    0.967257
3    0.987611
4    0.997788
5    0.987168
6    0.991150
Name: Close, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Ack!!  Sorry, I copied the example out of Excel, and I didn't notice it "modified" the contents.  Here's what's *actually* in the test file:

Date,Close
1/1/1979,226
1/2/1979,226.8
1/3/1979,218.6
1/4/1979,223.2
1/5/1979,225.5
1/8/1979,223.1
1/9/1979,224

Sorry, I can't figure out how to make this comment editor leave the formatting alone.  Each line is like `1979-01-01,123.45`.

I'll look at your test tomorrow.  Right now it's way past my bedtime and I'm more likely to mess up again.  Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Ugh.  Didn't notice it converted the format again.  The lines in the file are actually like `1/2/1979,226.8`.

Comment: OK @constantstranger, since the input file IS actually a CSV, with comma separators, I didn't need the `sep='  '` or the `engine='python'` bits.  It read in the file properly, with "Date" and "Close" headers.  But then, with or without the `engine=` it got a KeyError.  I'm still learning Python & pandas so I'm a bit clueless, but I guessed that the difference in reading the header may have messed it up.  So I changed the `sim_leverage` call to `sim = sim_leverage(base)`, no `[1]`.  Sure enough, no more KeyError -- but now I'm back to "unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'" ...

Comment: Please see my updated answer based on an updated .csv file that uses commas and contains a column header line. In my original code, it was calling `base[1]` which worked because the name of the column containing the floats was actually `1`, but with the updated.csv file there is no column named `1`, instead the relevant column is named `Close`.

Comment: The "unsupported operand types" error when you used `sim = sim_leverage(base)` is because `pct_change()` tries to do its work on each column in base, and base has `Date` as its first column which has values of type `str`.

Comment: Thanks @constantstranger, that makes sense.  Since I DO have a column label, I changed the call to `sim_leverage(base["Close"], ...`.  I believe my major confusion comes from trying to write code that had to work with the result of both read_csv (Dataframe, but requires `set_index`) and web.DataReader (Series, requires to_frame).  I'd get it working with one, but the other failed.  Fix that, and the first one breaks.  *sigh*  I'm certain there must be a better way.

Comment: Perhaps there's a better way, but in any case it sounds like you've got `read_csv()` working now. Do you need any more help on this? If you're satisfied with my answer, please mark it "accepted" when you have a chance.

Comment: Well @constantstranger I can get part of it to work, but then it breaks something else.  I haven't gotten the whole thing to work yet.  But your answer was helpful, and I can mark it accepted if it's important.  But first, one last piece of the puzzle... I tried a small test and I was able to index into both a Series and a Dataframe to get the last element, e.g. frame[-1].  But in my full example, it fails with a KeyError on a Series.  The output of sim_leverage was a DataFrame, then I renamed the column, and that converted it to a Series (!?).  Then series[-1] did not work!?  Any insights?

Comment: BTW that was the read_csv() case.  It works with the DataReader case.

Comment: You said "output of sim_leverage was a DataFrame, then I renamed the column ... Then series[-1] did not work". Can you show the code you used on the output of `sim_leverage` and be more specific about how series[-1] did not work?

Comment: Nevermind.  :-)  I found the difference between DataReader and read_csv:  read_csv was returning a numeric index column, which confused something, resulting in (among other symptoms) problems with series[-1].  I had noticed that before but it didn't really register.  I added `index_col="Date"` and `parse_dates=["Date"]` and now it's working, with DataReader AND read_csv.  Huzzah !!  I had one final problem:  somehow some Excel formatting had snuck into my CSV file, e.g. numbers represented as `"1,234.56"`. 
 Removed the " and , and all was good.  Thanks much for your patient help!